Is underlayment needed between subfloor and finish plywood?
Going to install 5/8' sanded plywood over OSB subfloor.  CO mountain build at 9000 ft.  Enclosed crawl space under single story home.  Should I put something like Quietwalk Plus underlayment down before I nail top layer of plywood?

No, you should not put a cushion underlayment between layers of sheathing. That's not what it's for, and the only way it really can work in that scenario is if the fasteners through your plywood slip under foot traffic. You definitely don't want that. Cushion underlayment is only appropriate under floating floors.

Someone disagrees. Yet... no counter to my position.
